# The maas/stable/ubuntu xenial repository does not have a Release file

Tags: server, apt, 16.04, maas

When I run `sudo apt update` on my Ubunutu 16.04 LTS Server with MAAS installed I get the following error message:

```
graeme@MAAS:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maas/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maas/stable/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/maas/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is this something I should ignore or try and fix?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there isn't a stable release of MAAS for Xenial which means I need to be on the  `ppa:maas/next` repository instead of `ppa:maas/stable`. The issue was brought about after stepping through the [MAAS getting started guide](http://maas.io/get-started) which wanted asked me to ad the `ppa:maas/stable` repository. After removing it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:maas/stable
```

The update went without any errors.

Comment: Did you also use `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maas/next` or just remove the old repo?